# Regex for Name, Streetname, Cityname, etc

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I m programming a web application with asp.net mvc and c#.
In a form a user should enter a name, a streetname and a city in different fields.

1. **Start:** The entered value has to start with an 'alphabetic' character (no matter if the language is english, chinese or french or what ever. So things like é and chinese chars and so on are ok. But chars like *¥@#1 and so on are not allowed)
2. **Middle:** The same as i said first and spaces (but not two spaces after eachother).
3. **End:** That what I have said for the start.

**This is correct:**

- A b c
- Abcd ef
- Abcdef

**This is not correct:**

- 1abc
- A1 bc
- 1 2 3
- a b c (space at the start)

**Question:**

- What is the correct regex for this?
- How can i set the length?
- In a second case I want to allow numbers 0123456789 too (like the chars)

This is what I have: '^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ][a-zA-Z]$'

Thank you

Comment: Are spaces at the end acceptable?

Comment: No, only chars that are acceptable for the first char are acceptable for the last one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to validate strings that only contain letter words separated with a single space between them.

You may use a regex like

```
^\p{L}+(?: \p{L}+)*$
```

Or, if any whitepsace is allowed:

```
^\p{L}+(?:\s\p{L}+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B%28%3F%3A%20%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B%29*%5Cr%3F%24&i=A%20b%20c%0D%0AAbcd%20ef%0D%0AAbcdef%0D%0A%0D%0A1abc%0D%0AA1%20bc%0D%0A1%202%203%0D%0AA%20%20%20bc&o=m)

To make it only match strings of 3 or more chars, use

```
^(?=.{3})\p{L}+(?:\s\p{L}+)*$
 ^^^^^^^^
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?=.{3})` = a positive lookahead that requires any 3 chars immediately after the start of a string
- `\p{L}+` - 1 or more any Unicode letters
- `(?:\s\p{L}+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\s` - any whitespace
  - `\p{L}+` - 1 or more any Unicode letters
- `$` - end of string

Note that if you need to use it in ASP.NET, only use this regex to validate on the *server* side, as on the client side, this pattern might not be correctly handled by JavaScript regex.

Comment: Can you tell me how i can make sure that the entered value is at least 3 chars long? With the regex i used before it was forcing the lenght to 3 or more.

Comment: @huckjulius Use `^(?=.{3})\p{L}+(?:\s\p{L}+)*$`

Comment: Sorry that I have to ask again :)
I want the regex to also accept numbers like characters.

Comment: @huckjulius If you only need to allow ASCII digits, replace all `\p{L}` with `[\p{L}0-9]`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5cp%7bL%7d0-9%5d%2b%28%3f%3a+%5b%5cp%7bL%7d0-9%5d%2b%29*%5cr%3f%24&i=A+b+c%0d%0aAbcd+ef%0d%0aAbcdef%0d%0a%0d%0a1abc%0d%0aA1+bc%0d%0a1+2+3%0d%0aA+++bc&o=m).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:\p{L}+ )*\p{L}+$
```

`\p{L}` matches all unicode code points that are in the "Letters" category.

The regex matches 0 or more of `\p{L}+` (one or more letters plus a space) and then ensures there is at least one or more letters.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JtqTCM/2)

Example code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("abc def", @"^(?:\p{L}+ )*\p{L}+$"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But does this filter out all special characters? And when how?

Comment: @huckjulius `\p{L}` _only_ matches letters. And the regex is anchored on the start and end.

Comment: You should not make the space optional, else, the pattern becomes very inefficient, and with very long non-matching strings leads to catastrophical backtracking.

Comment: I will hse it for 3-256 chars

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Edited. Yours is still better though :)

Comment: @huckjulius That is not a problem if the string matches, the problem appears when a long string does not match. If you limit the number of chars to type in the input field, then it is OK, but a pattern that can be reduced to `^(A+)+$` is a very bad practice.